# Combine 2 while loop results

Tags: php, while-loop

We have **2 while loops** , we are displaying **2 different results** with both.

we need to **combine** or without combining we need to merge 2 results.

in below image ,

**1st while** loop result = >  1st, 2nd, 6th rows.

**2nd while** loop result = >  3rd, 4th, 5th rows.

we need 3rd , 4th & 5th rows results in 1st, 2nd 6th rows in last 2 columns [ Paid status & commission ].

1st while results coming from Database 1 & 2nd while results are coming from Database 2 with table [**order_details**]

[image]

[image]

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");  
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();

$i = 0; 

foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
$k = 0; 
$orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id']; 
$orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems); 

/* 1st while */
while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))    
{ 

if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') 
{ 

$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details"); 
$stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id'])); 
$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status']; 

$productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]); 
$designer_id = $productdetail->getDesignerID() ; 

if($accountType == "admin")
{ 
$designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")"; 

$responce[] = array( 
$orderData->getIncrementId() ,  
$orderitemsarray[$k], 
$productdetail->getName() , 
$designerName, 
$orderData['status'],                 
$data['dpaid_status'],
$data['commission'],
$sDate                             
); 

}
}

$k++; 
$i++; 
} 

/* 2nd while */

while($data = $stmt->fetch())   
{   

$responce[] = array( 
$data['dorder_id'],
$data['dpaid_status'],
$data['commission']
); 
$k++;
}   
}
```

I tried below code , but it results as below image - means only 2 rows displayed instead of 23 rows....

```
while (($k < count($orderitemsarray)) &&  ($data = $stmt->fetch()))
```

[image]

Full page looks as below :

[image]

I am new to php world & tried lot before posting here....

Comment: its really hurt a lot to get downvote for good question...... atleast you can leave a comment and inform whats wrong , so that i will learn from my mistake.....

Comment: It's sad some1 downvoted without reading it properly i got your question but Sorry i don't know magento can you pls tell which var holds your array? Or can i assume my sample data as per your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is whenever you use empty brackets [] an index is automatically assigned which is equal to the next available numeric value and your data ends up in a next position so correct index is equired to solve this issue .

In while `(($k < count($orderitemsarray)) &&  ($data = $stmt->fetch()))`

If either of condition fails then loop ends and your `$data` probably has only three entries it's showing only that many even though `$orderitemsarray` has many more , i am not sure but you can prolly replace `while` with `if` statement and change index like this to make those stuff append on same row

```
$indx=0;

foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 
  $k = 0; 
//.. Stufff

/* 2nd while */
if($indx == 0 || $indx == 1 || $indx == 5)
{
  if($data = $stmt->fetch())   
  {   
    $size = count($responce); // get size from that get its last index
    $responce[$size-1] = array(
      $data['dorder_id'],
      $data['dpaid_status'],
      $data['commission']
    ); 
   $k++; //<-- not sure why it's here but doesn't matter may be some magento stuff?
  }  
}
$indx++
}
```

EDIT:sry my bad , ignore my last comment try this instead

```
   $responce[$size-1] =  array_merge($responce[$size-1] , array(
      $data['dorder_id'],
      $data['dpaid_status'],
      $data['commission']
    ) );
```

Comment: Hmm. try removing `$indx` and its conditions

Comment: Grats you made it work!! , i did nothing more than a few random guesses but i think i've learnt something thank u .. n Cheers! :)